# how to change the prefix in .pc files of libraries that installed in different location by yum?

Tags: pkg-config

I've installed standard libraries into the non-standard location such as /usr or /usr/local for the management of linux system. So, I've installed libraries in $HOME/mylibs and I can find pkg-config files in $HOME/mylibs/lib64/pkgconfig.

But, the problem is the prefix path in pkg-config file(.pc) is heading to wrong location. For example, prefix path in .pc file of AA library installed in $HOME/mylibs is /usr, not $HOME/mylibs/usr. Below is the part of output for AA library.

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=/usr
libdir=/usr/lib64
includedir=/usr/include
```

Could I define the prefix path for pkg-config file of libaries which is installed in non-standard location by yum ?

Thanks in advance.

```
prefix=$HOME/mylibs/usr
exec_prefix=$HOME/mylibs/usr
libdir=$HOME/mylibs/usr/lib64
includedir=$HOME/mylibs/usr/include
```